# How to make an output layer of size 5 when my output labels are even numbers in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have labels 0,2,4,6,8 in my training data. So, technically, I have 5 classes but when I write the following code,

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu",input_shape=[784]),
    layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(units=5,activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

history = model.fit(
    training_X, training_Y.reshape(2465,1),
    validation_data=(val_X, val_Y.reshape(986,1)),
    epochs=50,
    verbose = 1
)
```

I get this error,

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 8 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 6 8 4 6 2 4 8 0 2 2 4 6 0 2 6 4 4 2 2 8 0 0 6 0 2 8 0 2 2 6 4 4
```

So, how do I use only 5 output units and train it for these labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error you received, your integer labels should more like `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` instead of `0,2,4,6,8`. You can convert your labels to solve the issue or you can transform your labels to an **on-hot** encoded vector as follows.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

x = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(5, 784)).astype("float32")
y = pd.get_dummies(np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])).values
x.shape, y.shape
((5, 784), (5, 5))

y
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

And additionally, you also need to use the `categorical_crossentropy` loss function instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. Full working code:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu",input_shape=[784]),
    layers.Dense(units=512, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(units=5,activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

history = model.fit(
    x, y,
    epochs=3, verbose=2
)

Epoch 1/3
380ms/step - loss: 153.8635 - accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 2/3
16ms/step - loss: 194.0642 - accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 3/3
16ms/step - loss: 259.9468 - accuracy: 0.6000
```